# NodeJS Request tracing

Tags: node.js, performance, apm

I recently configured my application to use monitoring of most commonly used queries ( its a graphql server ). The monitoring includes, among others, ability to sort queries by response time and popularity. Given these two, I can figure out which queries are good candidates for optimizations/caching.

What tools or techniques can I use to then break down and troubleshoot an http request in my local environment?

I'm looking for something that would help me visualize and measure the smaller components that make up an http request, like

- response time
- redis queries
- sql query count - track n + 1 queries
- sql query start/end time - track slow or consecutive queries

To get an idea, some of the things that I looked into are Clinic's Bubbleprof ( the interface is pretty hard for me to navigate ) and Jaeger.

I do not need persistent storage ( like Datadog ), I'm looking for something to use on my local machine to improve an endpoint that I already has a problem.

Is my best bet to get a Jaeger instance going through docker and use that or is there something better?

Comment: Can't you just run the profiler? Run your node server in debugger mode. Connect Google Chorme to your server to act as the debugger GUI. Start the profiler and start making requests. After some time (or some number of requests) stop the profiler and you will have a graphical view of your program running.

Comment: Its not the best tool for async debugging and it doesn't really visualize graphically in the same way that I would like it to, see here for example https://www.jaegertracing.io/img/trace-detail-ss.png